# Underscore sign change accessibility of variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In angular I have two files 
in the first file

```
private _test: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

In the second file

```
test$: Observable<Object> = this.test2;
```

when I change in first file .ts variable from _test to test I have an error

```
Property 'test' is private and only accessible within the class
```

In some article:

A convention has also developed regarding the use of _, which is frequently used to preface the name of an object's property or method that is private

Why using underscore sign project compiles without errors?

Comment: Do you have anything else in your class ? like `get test() { ... } `

Comment: @Nicolas I have get test() {...} method

Comment: It's up to you to keep public property OR get/set along with private property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In typescript / Javascript ES6, getter are defined that way:

```
get test() : any {
    return this._test;
}
```

because of that, you can't have both a property and a function with the same name.
This is also why, when generating getter/setter, your IDE will usually renamed the property with underscore (`_`).

You could rename the property to remove the underscore, changing it's visibility to public, and remove the function. in both case Your property will be accessible like that `obj.test`.